# MongoDB query with subtraction on time not working?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{'field.timestamp': {'$lt': Date()}, 'field.timestamp': {'$gt': new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60) } }
```

returns:

> "JSON parsing error: Invalid date format at line 1, col 83"

Comment: My current query is `{'field.timestamp': {'$lt': new Date()}, 'field.timestamp': {'$gt': new Date( ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15 ) } }`, and I get "JSON parsing error: Invalid date format at line 1, col 88"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `new` keyword as well as duplicating keys `'field.timestamp'`. If you are querying a date range from now and 15 days ago, then the correct query should be:

```
var fifteenDaysAgo = new Date(),
    today = new Date();
fifteenDaysAgo.setDate(fifteenDaysAgo.getDate() - 15);

db.my_collection.find({ 'field.timestamp': { '$lt': today, '$gt': fifteenDaysAgo } });
```

Comment: I still get an error.  I think this is just invalid JSON and unfortunately just doesn't work (although I thought I had seen something similar done elsewhere).  I ended up doing something like:

    date = ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15;

    query = {    'field.timestamp': {        '$lt': new Date(),        '$gt': new Date( date )     } };

    db.my_collection.find(query);

Comment: Updated answer, please try agin to see if that works for you.